# How to show $t^2\mathbb{1}_{\{X>r\}}\geq(X-r)(2t+r-X)$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Let $X$ be a (real)random variable and $r,t>0$. How do you prove the following inequality, $$t^2\mathbb{1}_{\{X>r\}}\geq(X-r)(2t+r-X)\space ?$$

I can see why it is true but have no idea how to show it so any help with this is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the elementary events $\omega$ where $X(\omega)>r$ or  $X(\omega)\leq r$ separately, and compare both sides for each case.

Comment: This is a deterministic inequality between real-valued functions, which involves no probability. First show that for every $z$ and every nonnegative $t$, $$z(2t-z)\leqslant t^2$$ everywhere and $$z(2t-z)\leqslant 0$$ for every $z\leqslant0$ hence $$z(2t-z)\leqslant t^2\mathbf 1_{z>0}$$ everywhere. Finally, use this for $$z=X-r$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that each side of the inequality is a function mapping from a probability space (say, $\Omega$) to $\mathbb{R}$. So the inequality is saying for every $\omega\in\Omega$, $t^21_{\{X>r\}}(\omega)\ge (X(\omega)-r)(2t+r-X(\omega))$. As NCh suggests, consider the events $B=\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)>r\}$ and $B^c$. This partitions $\Omega$.

For $\omega\in B$, evaluate both sides at $\omega$ (in particular, $1_{\{X>r\}}(\omega)=1$ and rearrange to get the equivalent inequality $(t-(X-r))^2\ge0$, which is clearly true.

For $\omega\in B^c$, evaluate both sides at $\omega$ and rearrange to get a true inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$$(t-(\xi-r))^2\geq0$$ 
$$\therefore t^2\geq 2t(\xi-r)-(\xi-r)^2=(\xi-r)(2t+r-\xi)$$
and the RHS is non-positive when $r\geq\xi$.